# Show surjectivity of Backward shifting $T: F^{\infty} \Rightarrow F^{\infty}$ defined as $T(x_1,x_2,...) =(x_2,x_3,....)$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

First what is the range of Backward shifting $T: F^{\infty} \rightarrow F^{\infty}$ defined as $T(x_1,x_2,...) =(x_2,x_3,....)$

Then to show that $T$ is surjective, I must show that $\operatorname{Range}(T)=F^\infty$.

And I know I have to show that $\operatorname{Range}(T) \subset F^\infty$ and $F^\infty \subset \operatorname{Range}(T)$. But I'm not able to show it.

So if someone can help be would be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* What is $T(0,x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots)$ ?

Comment: Well this is just $(x_1,x_2,x_3,...)$ but is it enough and is it $legal$ to do that ?

Comment: @SamiMir, I assumed that $F$ was a field and so contained $0$.  You can also use $T(x_1,x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots)=(x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots)$.